# Recursively enter Month Year Name between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I'm trying to insert the followings columns below into a #table based off a time range.

For example if the query is run in August 2020, I'd need it to insert Months names from **Jan - July 2020**

```
Report_Date_Name|   Report_Date_Month|  DateYrmo|   DateYear|   DateMonth|
January     2020|             January|    202001|       2020|           1|
February    2020|            February|    202002|       2020|           2|
March       2020|               March|    202003|       2020|           3|
April       2020|               April|    202004|       2020|           4|
May         2020|                 May|    202005|       2020|           5|
June        2020|                June|    202006|       2020|           6|
July        2020|                July|    202007|       2020|           7|


________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: SQL Server version?

Answer (score 4):

A recursive CTE seems like a simple approach:

```
with dates as (
      select datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < getdate()
     )
select concat(convert(char(12), datename(month, dte)), year(dte)) as report_date_name,
       datename(month, dte) as report_date_month,
       year(dte) * 100 + month(dte) as year_month,
       year(dte) as year
from dates;
```

It is not clear if the last columns are strings or numbers.  If strings, just cast them to the type you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a5b2788f1938e37dab7da57166093c0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SomeDate DATE = '2020-08-08';

WITH Dates ([Date]) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -[number], '2020-08-08')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT [number] + 1
        FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values]
        WHERE [type] = 'P'
    ) n ([number])
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, -[number], @SomeDate) <= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @SomeDate)
        AND YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -[number], @SomeDate)) = YEAR(@SomeDate)
)
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]), ' ', YEAR([Date])) AS [Report_Date_Name]
      ,DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]) AS [Report_Date_Month]
      ,RIGHT(YEAR([Date]) * 100 + 10000000 + MONTH([Date]), 6) AS [DateYrmo]
      ,YEAR([Date]) AS [DateYear]
      ,MONTH([Date]) AS [DateMonth]
FROM Dates
ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
```

The CTE is used to generated one date from each previous month for the current year. Then we are using built-in functions to format the output.

[image]